# haproxy stickiness: cookie vs stick-table

Tags: haproxy

I have an haproxy (1.6.3) balancing between to rails servers.  I implemented stickiness with a cookie:

```
backend railswebapp-backend
    balance roundrobin
    mode http
    redirect scheme code 301 https if !{ ssl_fc }
    cookie SERVER_NAME insert
{% for backend_fqdn in backend_fqdns %}
    server {{ backend_fqdn }} {{ backend_fqdn }}:443 ssl cookie {{ backend_fqdn }} check
{% endfor %}
```

(I'm copy/pasting from a salt template: that last line just means that each server's FQDN is used as the server name and the cookie value.)

This seems to be working.  But I've read that cookie (and appsession, which I'm not using) are deprecated in favour of stick-table.

Aside from the future-compatibility of using current feature sets, is there a performance reason to prioritise changing this?  Or did I miss somethign in testing?  Or is this merely that it makes more sense from a development standpoint for haproxy to move in this direction, and so I should follow before I arrive at an haproxy version that no longer supports cookie, but otherwise all is well?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using the `cookie` keyword for [proxies](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.9/configuration.html#4-cookie) and [servers](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.9/configuration.html#5.2-cookie).  For these contexts, I don't see anything that indicates that the `cookie` keyword will be deprecated.  I also can't find any discussion online about it, so if you can link the article discussing this it would be very helpful.  The only context I could find where the keyword has been deprecated is that it was made less ambiguous for [fetching samples](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.9/configuration.html#7.3.6-cookie); `cookie` was deprecated in favor of `req.cook` and `res.cook`.

For `appsession`, the reason for it being removed is that the use case was too narrow, and sticktables could do the same thing but in a more flexible and robust way.  From the [docs](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.9/configuration.html#4.2-appsession):

```
As of version 1.6, appsessions was removed. It is more flexible and more
convenient to use stick-tables instead, and stick-tables support multi-master
replication and data conservation across reloads, which appsessions did not.
```